# convert array as a string with a delimiter : angular

Tags: angular

I have a type script file.

My requirement is to convert an array as a string.

```
     contextObj.shHandles = JSON.parse(returnvalue["Data"]["FieldBinderData"])
                        var spacehandlestring = contextObj.shHandles.Join(contextObj.rowDelimiter);
```

but it shows error. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  **JSON.stringify()** to convert an array to string

```
contextObj.shHandles = JSON.parse(returnvalue["Data"]["FieldBinderData"]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(contextObj.shHandles));
```

Comment: I don't need the delimiter as comma, I need to specify the delimiter, what to do then?